# How keep line breaks in Request Body which is send to Spring Boot rest controller

Tags: python, spring-boot, http, post, line-breaks

I'm quite confused.

I'm sending a String via Http Post request to a Spring Boot rest controller.

The string contains line breaks which are represented by '\n'.

The controller consumes 'plain/text'.

The client is a python programm which reads the the string from the field in a json object which is read from a text file.

The json object in the text file looks like this:
{"content": "Multi \n line \n string"}

However, the new line characters are escaped if they arrives on the rest controller to '\\n' so that they will display as normal '\n' as part of the string.

I tried to send a string from python which is not read from the text file. Instead I provide the string direct in a variable with newlines:

```
payload = "new \n line \n string"
headers = {'content-type': 'text/plain'}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

But '\n' is escaped to '\\n' which makes it to a normal part of the string which display like "new \n line \n string" instead of
"new
 line
 string".

But if I send the string via Postman like this, the new lines are interpreted correct as '\r\n' in the string that arrives to the controller(text/plain header is set):

[image: Post via Postman]

So my specific question is, how to send the string I read from the json field from python to the rest controller so that java/spring-boot don't escaped the '\n' character but rather interpret it as new line character.
Is there a way to send the string from python correct(prefered way) or have I to do some conversion/encoding on spring server side?

If I have to do the conversion/encoding on spring server side, how to ensure that If I post with my python client to a server I have no control over, will interpret new line characters correct?
Is there any standart or those it depend on the server side custom conversion/encoding?

The controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
class SmoeController {

    @PostMapping("/some-endpoint",  consumes = "text/plain", produces = 
                 "text/plain")
    String newEmployee(@RequestBody String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
        return text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this String[] lines = payload.split("\r\n");